# How do I setup Mysql with a blank/empty password on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, passwords

Attempting to log in to mysql as root user with an empty password leads to

`access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First make sure you are root, as non root users cannot login to mysql root user  with empty password:

`$ sudo su`

Next log in to mysql

`# mysql -uroot`

If this gives you access denied, we need to (re)set a password to log in with, which we can then later remove:

`# mysql_secure_installation`

Follow the prompts, and then try and log in again with your newly passworded root user, using the password you provided in the previous step.

`# mysql -uroot  -p`

After you are logged in to mysql:

`use mysql;
update user set authentication_string=password(''), plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';
flush privileges;`

Now log out, exit root and log in to mysql root user under your normal account:

`exit # exit mysql
 # exit # exit root user back to normal ubuntu user account
 $ mysql -uroot # log back in to mysql under your non-root ubuntu user account`